# How can this be functional iMacros script

Tags: javascript, imacros

I have a list of links .csv 2700 link
I want the script to go in the first 30 link
then disconnect from the account
then access to the account number two
then continue with the list starting with the 31 link
and continue so to finish the whole list

Please help!

Sorry for bad English.

```js
var list; 
    list =  "CODE:";
    list +=  "SET !DATASOURCE file1.csv" + "\n";
    list +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1" + "\n";
    list +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{i}}" + "\n";
    list +=  "URL GOTO={{!COL1}}" + "\n";
    list +=  "WAIT SECONDS = 5" + "\n";
 
 


for(i=1;i<=2700;i++){
iimSet("i",i);
iimPlay("account1_login.iim")
iimPlay(list);
iimPlay("Scroll_down_ok.iim")
iimPlay("account_logout.iim")
}

for(i=1;i<=2700;i++){
iimSet("i",i);
iimPlay("account2_login.iim")
iimPlay(list);
iimPlay("Scroll_down_ok.iim")
iimPlay("account_logout.iim")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood this issue, you just need two loops with different iterators:

```
// ...

iimPlay("account1_login.iim");
for (i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
    iimSet("i",i);
    iimPlay(list);
    iimPlay("Scroll_down_ok.iim");
}
iimPlay("account_logout.iim");

iimPlay("account2_login.iim");
for (i = 31; i <= 2700; i++) {
    iimSet("i",i);
    iimPlay(list);
    iimPlay("Scroll_down_ok.iim");
}
iimPlay("account_logout.iim");
```

Comment: No
I am 100 accounts.
It is necessary to go through all accounts
until it finishes the list

Answer (score 0):

I am 100 accounts.
It is necessary to go through all accounts
until it finishes the list

Comment: How many times would you like to play `… iimPlay(list) …` for each of your 100 accounts? 30 times as in the case with the first one?